# Are there any good frameworks for automated testing of AWT GUIs?

Tags: java, unit-testing, awt, automated-tests, gui-testing

Are there any good frameworks for automated testing of AWT GUIs?

Integration with JUnit would be a plus.

Answer (score 2):

[FEST](https://web.archive.org/web/20110201033502/http://fest.easytesting.org/) is your best bet.

It is, at its heart, a JUnit/ Test-NG style test framework; and its key feature is fluent interfaces around the `Robot` class.

While it is intended for testing Swing applications, I believe you can also [test AWT applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20110201033502/http://easytesting.org/swing/apidocs/org/fest/swing/awt/AWT.html) with it.

Also, due to its roots and history, it is very much similar to xUnit style testing, so integration with JUnit should be easy. It also has plugins for both Netbeans and Eclipse IDEs, allowing you to run unit tests within your development environment.

The main drawback though, is that you cannot "record" test cases, as some test tools/ frameworks allow you to. You will have to code the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try [marathon](http://www.marathontesting.com/Marathon.html) or [abbot](http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml). I used abbot in the past but marathon seems to be developed more actively and abbot seems to be quite stale.

Comment: Marathon is not being developed actively at all, it's sourceforge has been dead for about 18 months, and 2.0 has been in beta for that long. Their developers do respond to queries on their google groups forums though. Also, I might ad that the OP asked for AWT automated testing. Marathon only supports Swing.

Comment: @bguiz, probably you're right that marathon is stale too. I just know that a couple of years ago it was looking fresher than abbot. And hoped that it was developed further since than, it's a bad news that it's not.

Comment: Yeah I use marathon myself, and it is among the better ones out there that are free (if you require a tool that can record and replay). Certainly a lot better than abbott.
H/w if deciding to use it, you need to be prepared for its developers' complete lack of response to bug reports and feature requests.